# How to count data in mysql several times?

Tags: mysql

I need to take a result in this query.

```
Select count(*) from users where cardnumber IN (1,2,3,1,2);
```

In table users;

```
 Username    cardnumber   
          A          1  
          B          2  
          C          3
```

I need to get result as "5" because I want query count 2 times "1" . Reason; There are double "1" inside IN ...But I got result only "3" because After "1,2,3" it doesn't count again "1,2". I hope I can explain. How can I do this? thanks

Comment: This looks like trying to do something the wrong way. It would be helpful if you could tell us what you are *actually* trying to achieve.

Comment: My colleague ask me this query. I know it's complicate. She wants this query count double time in condition ( where cardnumber IN (1,1) ) .. normally it doesn't count second "1" in IN clause.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking.  If there are three records which match your `WHERE` clause, then the count of those records is going to be 3.  What makes you think it should be 5?

Comment: In this query, she tried to count more than table records.

Answer (score 0):

I think these sql will useful to you. Please check it.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users a RIGHT JOIN
(SELECT '1' AS  cardnumber
UNION ALL
SELECT '2'
UNION ALL
SELECT '3'
UNION ALL
SELECT '1'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2') b ON a.cardnumber = b.cardnumber
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to count two of the values twice you could use a sum with case when

```
select sum(
case when cardnumber = 1 then 2 
when cardnumber = 2 then 1 
when cardnumber = 3 then 2 END
) from users
```

How about this then? She can just change the IN list and add 4

```
SELECT SUM(c1.cnt + c2.cnt)
FROM (SELECT count(*) AS cnt from users) c1
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT count(*) AS cnt 
    from users WHERE cardnumber 
    in (1, 3)) 
c2 ON 1 = 1
```

Comment: it is nice. but when she add value "4" as cardnumber in users and ask "4" IN condition, she should change query..

Comment: @AhmetMelihBaşbuğ I updated the answer, this might be easier for her.